# How to visualize my training history in pytorch?

Tags: matplotlib, pytorch, graph-visualization

How do you guys visualize the training history of your pytorch model like in keras [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/).

I have a pytorch trained model and I want to see the graph of its training. 
Can I do this using only matplotlib? If yes, can someone give me resources to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the loss while training. A trained model won't have history of its loss. You need to train again.

Save the loss while training then plot it against the epochs using matplotlib. In your training function, where loss is being calculated save that to a file and visualize it later.
Also, you can use tensorboardX if you want to visualize in realtime.

This is a tutorial for tensorboardX: http://www.erogol.com/use-tensorboard-pytorch/

Comment: How can I save the loss? put it in a new variable? Sorry I really don't know.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/0T9A4GH here is the code. Originally I got the code from https://github.com/paraschopra/one-network-many-uses . Hope you can help me :)

Comment: at line 49. write that loss to a file.

Comment: to a text file or to put in a variable?

Comment: as i said to a text file